# Repainting Graphics Issue

Tags: java, swing, graphics, keylistener

I've been trying to write a small side-scroller game, but ran into an issue with repaint() not repainting. The key listener itself works, it increments and decrements the x and y values when the directional keys are pressed. Just the repaint() doesn't seem to be repainting.

```
public class SideScroller extends JPanel implements KeyListener{
private Random random = new Random();
private int r,g,b;
private int x = 0, y = 0;

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    if(e.getKeyCode() == e.VK_UP) {
        y -= 5;
    } else if(e.getKeyCode() == e.VK_DOWN) {
        y += 5;
    } else if(e.getKeyCode() == e.VK_LEFT) {
        x -= 5;
    } else if(e.getKeyCode() == e.VK_RIGHT) {
        x += 5;
    }
    repaint();
}
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {}
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}

public void paint(Graphics gg) {
    gg.setColor(new Color(r, g, b));
    gg.fillRect (x, y, 50, 50);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SideScroller ss = new SideScroller();
    JFrame f = new JFrame();

    f.add(new SideScroller());
    f.setSize(500, 500);
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    f.setResizable(false);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setVisible(true);
    f.addKeyListener(new SideScroller());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You should be overriding `paintComponent` and calling `super.paintComponent`, not `paint`.

  ```
  protected void paintComponent(Graphics gg) {
      super.paintComponent(gg);
      gg.setColor(new Color(r, g, b));
      gg.fillRect (x, y, 50, 50);
  }
  ```
- Also I'd recommend looking into using [Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) instead of `KeyListener`,
- Also you should be running Swing apps on the Event Dispacth Thread You can d so by wrapping the code in the `main` in a `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...)`

Here are all the fixes mentioned above

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.ActionMap;
import javax.swing.InputMap;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class SideScroller extends JPanel {

    private Random random = new Random();
    private int r, g, b;
    private int x = 0, y = 0;

    public SideScroller() {
        InputMap im = getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
        ActionMap am = getActionMap();
        im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("UP"), "upaction");
        am.put("upaction", new AbstractAction() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                y -= 5;

                repaint();
            }
        });
        im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("DOWN"), "downaction");
        am.put("downaction", new AbstractAction() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                y += 5;
                repaint();
            }
        });
        im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("LEFT"), "leftaction");
        am.put("leftaction", new AbstractAction() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                x -= 5;
                repaint();
            }
        });
        im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("RIGHT"), "rightaction");
        am.put("rightaction", new AbstractAction() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                x += 5;
                repaint();
            }
        });
    }

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics gg) {
        super.paintComponent(gg);

        gg.setColor(new Color(r, g, b));
        gg.fillRect(x, y, 50, 50);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JFrame f = new JFrame();

                f.add(new SideScroller());
                f.setSize(500, 500);
                f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                f.setResizable(false);
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: You're right about calling invokeLater, but I disagree with your other points. For a game JPanel, you presumably want to control all aspects of the appearance, so it makes sense to inhibit any default user-interface drawing or Graphics object configuration the L&F might try to do, so there's no sense calling `super.paintComponent`, and nothing wrong with overriding `paint` directly. Also, Swing's InputMap/ActionMap crap is annoyingly verbose and I've never understood why anyone would recommend it over a nice KeyListener for components that do/can have the keyboard focus.

Comment: @Boann `super.paint[Component]` clears the component of any paint artifacts. If you run my program and comment out the `super.paintComponent` you will see why you should call it. Also if you read the [KeyListener tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html) it even states `"To define special reactions to particular keys, use key bindings instead of a key listener"`

Comment: ‍@peeskillet Presumably the OP is going to fill the background with something. Clearing it twice, once with a JPanel color and once again with a game background, is just a performance hit. That tutorial page doesn't explain *why* it recommends key bindings, so that's a non-answer. There's no advantage to them in this case. A KeyListener works nicely.

Comment: @Boann: Key Bindings are considered a "higher level" construct than KeyListeners which are very low-level, which gives them greater risk of side effect. More importantly, Key Bindings are much more forgiving of focus issues and will not fail if the bound component loses focus as will happen with KeyListeners. Note that Key Bindings is how Swing itself finds keystrokes to actions in its own components. They are easier to turn on and turn off for each particular key...

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Shouldn't you want the component to stop responding to key events when it loses focus? "They are easier to turn on and turn off for each particular key". True, but you can also use your own keycode map in a KeyListener. Another point I'd forgotten: with key bindings, the action is triggered at an unknown rate. Using key listeners, although this is also true of the simple code in this question, it becomes possible to track press & release separately, using a timer to move the game character at a fixed speed regardless of how the user/OS has configured the key repeat rate.

Comment: @Boann: `"Shouldn't you want the component to stop responding to key events when it loses focus?"` -- Key Bindings have the flexibility, depending on which InputMap you use, of doing this, or not -- your choice.

Comment: @Boann: `"Another point I'd forgotten: with key bindings, the action is triggered at an unknown rate. Using key listeners, although this is also true of the simple code in this example, it becomes possible to track press & release separately, using a timer to move the game character at a fixed speed regardless of how the user/OS has configured the key repeat rate."` -- I often use Key Bindings together with a Swing Timer. I've had no frequency problems when using them this way.

Comment: @Boann: see code in my answer for an example of this.

Answer (score 1):

For the original poster and for Boann: Key Binding with a Swing Timer example:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.EnumMap;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class GamePanel extends JPanel {
   private static final int ANIMATION_DELAY = 15;
   private final int HEIGHT = 400;
   private final int WIDTH = 600;
   private Square square;
   private EnumMap<Direction, Boolean> dirMap = new EnumMap<>(Direction.class);
   private Map<Integer, Direction> keyToDir = new HashMap<>();
   private Timer animationTimer;

   public GamePanel() {
      for (Direction dir : Direction.values()) {
         dirMap.put(dir, Boolean.FALSE);
      }
      keyToDir.put(KeyEvent.VK_UP, Direction.UP);
      keyToDir.put(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN, Direction.DOWN);
      keyToDir.put(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, Direction.LEFT);
      keyToDir.put(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT, Direction.RIGHT);
      setKeyBindings();
      setBackground(Color.white);
      setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
      setFocusable(true);
      square = new Square();
      animationTimer = new Timer(ANIMATION_DELAY, new AnimationListener());
      animationTimer.start();
   }

   private void setKeyBindings() {
      int condition = WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW;
      final InputMap inputMap = getInputMap(condition);
      final ActionMap actionMap = getActionMap();
      boolean[] keyPressed = { true, false };
      for (Integer keyCode : keyToDir.keySet()) {
         Direction dir = keyToDir.get(keyCode);
         for (boolean onKeyPress : keyPressed) {
            boolean onKeyRelease = !onKeyPress;
            KeyStroke keyStroke = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(keyCode, 0,
                  onKeyRelease);
            Object key = keyStroke.toString();
            inputMap.put(keyStroke, key);
            actionMap.put(key, new KeyBindingsAction(dir, onKeyPress));
         }
      }
   }

   public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);
      square.display(g);
   }

   private class AnimationListener implements ActionListener {
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
         boolean repaint = false;
         for (Direction dir : Direction.values()) {
            if (dirMap.get(dir)) {
               square.move(dir);
               repaint = true;
            }
         }
         if (repaint) {
            repaint();
         }
      }
   }

   private class KeyBindingsAction extends AbstractAction {
      private Direction dir;
      boolean pressed;

      public KeyBindingsAction(Direction dir, boolean pressed) {
         this.dir = dir;
         this.pressed = pressed;
      }

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
         dirMap.put(dir, pressed);
      }
   }

   private static void createAndShowGUI() {
      GamePanel gamePanel = new GamePanel();
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("GamePanel");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(gamePanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);
      gamePanel.requestFocusInWindow();
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGUI();
         }
      });
   }
}

enum Direction {
   UP(0, -1), DOWN(0, 1), LEFT(-1, 0), RIGHT(1, 0);
   private int incrX;
   private int incrY;

   private Direction(int incrX, int incrY) {
      this.incrX = incrX;
      this.incrY = incrY;
   }

   public int getIncrX() {
      return incrX;
   }

   public int getIncrY() {
      return incrY;
   }
}

class Square {
   private int x = 0;
   private int y = 0;
   private int w = 20;
   private int h = w;
   private int step = 1;
   private Color color = Color.red;
   private Color fillColor = new Color(255, 150, 150);
   private Stroke stroke = new BasicStroke(3f, BasicStroke.CAP_ROUND,
         BasicStroke.JOIN_ROUND);

   public void display(Graphics g) {
      Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
      g2d.setColor(fillColor);
      g2d.fillRect(x, y, w, h);
      g2d.setStroke(stroke);
      g2d.setColor(color);
      g2d.drawRect(x, y, w, h);
      g2d.dispose();
   }

   public void setStep(int step) {
      this.step = step;
   }

   public void move(Direction dir) {
      x += step * dir.getIncrX();
      y += step * dir.getIncrY();
   }
}
```

Comment: Yup, you're right, I see your point now. I didn't realize it was possible with key bindings to separately track the press & release events (shows how much I avoid them). I always thought only KeyListener could do that.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is two things. You are adding the key listener to a **new** SideScroller - not the same one you are rendering, and you're not overwriting the correct painting method.

I suggest you add `addKeyListener(this);` to the SideScroller's constructor and removing `f.addKeyListener(new SideScroller());`, test that is getting called then testthe paint method which should be `paintComponent(Graphics g)`.

I hope you understand how to do this and why keys are being recognised but 'not' rendering, I don't believe providing code to beginners is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating three different SideScroller objects. One unused, a second which you add to the frame and is displayed, and the third which you use as a KeyListener only (which is the one the repaint() method is called on). The SideScroller that you put into the `ss` variable is the one you should also add to the frame and be using as the KeyListener.